# Fetch ISO-3166-2 code from Google Maps API. Is it possible?

Tags: google-maps, iso-3166

I need to match locations recorded with their coordinates (latitude/longitude) to the visitor's selection from an interactive map using region codes (ISO-3166-2).

Anyone has a take on this please? Not too sure how to go about it and/or if it's possible.

Comment: Added code for fetching. clarify what to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code for  fetching  region codes(ISO-3166-2) using google maps.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/50m6jfnh/)

Js

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

codeAddress = function () {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var address = document.getElementById('city_country').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 16,
            streetViewControl: false,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
              mapTypeIds:[google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP] 
    },
    center: results[0].geometry.location,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          draggable: true,
          title: 'My Title'
      });
      updateMarkerPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
      geocodePosition(results[0].geometry.location);

      // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition()); 
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    updateMarkerPosition(e.latLng);
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
    marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
  map.panTo(marker.getPosition()); 
  }); 

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      //updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);

  for (var i = 0; i < responses[0].address_components.length; i += 1) {
    var addressObj = responses[0].address_components[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < addressObj.types.length; j += 1) {
      if (addressObj.types[j] === 'country') {
        updateMarkerAddress(addressObj.short_name);
      }
    }
  }
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}
```

html

```
<body>
  <div id="panel">
      <input id="city_country" type="textbox" value="Dublin, Ireland">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </div>  
  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <b>Marker status:</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <b>Current position:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <b>Fetched ISO-3166-2 code from Google Maps API:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Disclaimer** code modified from [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/landwire/WppF6/24/)

Comment: That did the trick nicely. Thx... For those who are looking to drill down to regions or city you can replace addressObj.types[j] === 'country')

Comment: with: addressObj.types[j] === 'administrative_area_level_2')
or
addressObj.types[j] === 'administrative_area_level_1')